# In Java, how do I call the method of a overridden class from an instance of the overriding class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am new to Java Inheritance. Please see the code for my parent class called Term:

```
public class Term {

  public String value;
  public void setValue(String value)
  {
    this.value=value;
  }

  public String getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

}
```

Now class OperatorTerm extends Term

```
public class OperatorTerm extends Term {

  public static Operator type;

  public static boolean equals(String value)
  {
    String regex="(\\++)|(-+)|\\*|/";
    boolean isOperand=value.matches(regex);
    return isOperand;
  }

  public void assignType(String value)
  {
    if(value.equals("+"))
      type=Operator.ADD;
    else if(value.equals("-"))
      type=Operator.SUBTRACT;
    else if(value.equals("*"))
      type=Operator.MULTIPLY;
    else if(value.equals("/"))
      type=Operator.DIVIDE;
    else if(value.equals("++"))
      type=Operator.INCREMENT;
    else
      type=Operator.DECREMENT;
    }
  }
```

I am creating an OperatorTerm object like this in another class:

```
public static Term getTerm(String termValue)
{
  Term newTerm=null;
  if(ValueTerm.equals(termValue))
    newTerm=new ValueTerm();
  else if(ReferenceTerm.equals(termValue))
    newTerm=new ReferenceTerm();
  else if(OperatorTerm.equals(termValue))
  {
    newTerm=new OperatorTerm();
  }
  return newTerm;
}
```

In the last elseif statement, I want to do the following newTerm.assignType. assignType is a method in the OperatorTerm class but it is not present in the Term class. I am unable to do so, and I am wondering if someone can guide me on how can I use newTerm to access the methods of OperatorTerm class

I am creating an object of the overridden class using

Comment: Why is everything `static` in your child class?

Comment: only the equals method is but the assignType is not. Do you see any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    else if(OperatorTerm.equals(termValue))
    {
        OperatorTerm newOperatorTerm = new OperatorTerm();
        newOperatorTerm.assignType(...);
        newTerm = newOperatorTerm;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think are the pros and cons of your answer vs. newTerm=new OperatorTerm();
   ((OperatorTerm)newTerm).assignType(termValue);

Comment: Using an unnecessary downcast is clunky.  Plus the code is forced to do a check (unless the compiler is pretty good at optimizing).

Comment: Let's say after i have declared newTerm and initialized it, and returned it to another class. Now this class wants to call assignType method on variable newTerm, then what should be the best way to do so?

Comment: First you have to answer the question: how does this other class know that the value it got from `getTerm` is an `OperatorTerm`?  If it doesn't know that, it can't use `assignType`.

Comment: If it uses `instanceof`, it may be able to tell that it's an `OperatorTerm`.  Then the downcast makes sense.  `instanceof` is often used improperly, though.  Often, when you use `instanceof`, you should be thinking about how you could use polymorphism instead.

Comment: i typically do if (term.getClass().equals(OperatorTerm.class)) . is this correct?

Comment: This last won't work if another part of the program extends `OperatorTerm`. `instanceof` would return `true` but your `equals` would return `false`, but since you're trying to check whether you can call `assignType`, I think you want it to return `true`.  There are definitely places where you want to test classes for equality, but not here.  It's not a matter of style whether to use `equals` or `instanceof`, since the two have different effects, and you need to think carefully about which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call the method "newTerm.assignType" inside the getTerm method only, perhaps you just need to return and/or create the proper child objects:

```
public static Term getTerm(String termValue)
    {
        // Term newTerm=null;
        if(ValueTerm.equals(termValue))
            return new ValueTerm();
        else if(ReferenceTerm.equals(termValue))
            return new ReferenceTerm();
        else if(OperatorTerm.equals(termValue))
        {
            OperatorTerm newTerm=new OperatorTerm();
            newTerm.assignType("+");
            return newTerm;
        }
        // return newTerm;
    }
```

As a rule, you cannot use methods created in extended classes if the object that you are using is the parent one.

Hope my answer is useful for what you want to do.

Comment: What do you think are the pros and cons of your answer vs. newTerm=new OperatorTerm(); ((OperatorTerm)newTerm).assignType(termValue);

Comment: I guess that code will work... but is ugly!, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(OperatorTerm.equals(termValue))
{
    newTerm = new Operatorterm();
    ((OperatorTerm) newTerm).assignType(value);
}
```

Personally, I would do

```
else if(OperatorTerm.equals(termValue))
{
    OperatorTerm ot = new OperatorTerm();
    ot.assignType(value);
    return ot;
}
```

And do the same for the others.